# How to add a form as field attribute in a django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm for a Product object set up like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    compositon_choices = ((2L, u'Calcium (100mg)'), (3L, u'Iron (500mg)'))
        composition_selection = forms.\
              MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,      
                        choices=compositon_choices )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title', 'title_de', 'title_es', 'upc', 'description', 
            'description_en_gb', 'description_de',
            'description_es', 'is_discountable', 'structure',   
            'unit_type', 'product_concentration',]

        widgets = {
            'structure': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

In the example above I extended the ModelForm with a MultipleChoiceField by adding the composition_selection field (this works):

I would like the composoition_selection to be a form itself and not just a MultipleChoiceField:

```
class ProductComponentForm(forms.Form):
    component_amount = forms.IntegerField()
    component_name = forms.CharField()
```

and then extend the ModelForm with this new form like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
        composition_selection = ProductComponentForm()

        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = [
                'title', 'title_de', 'title_es', 'upc', 'description', 
                'description_en_gb', 'description_de',
                'description_es', 'is_discountable', 'structure',   
                'unit_type', 'product_concentration',]

            widgets = {
                'structure': forms.HiddenInput()
            }
```

But I cannot get this to work. This ProductForm that I want to create never gets rendered,and nothing appears. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? What would be the best way to extend a ModelForm with a SubForm?

Comment: What is the purpose of it? To have `component_amount` and `component_name` in `ProductForm` as two more fields?

Comment: A Product can have various ProductComponents. Every ProductComponent has a name and an amount. My goal would be to render a form where one can select various ProductComponents by checkbox and add the amount in an integer field next to the select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand what I did wrong. To make subforms in Django one needs formsets. 
In my case i needed two different types of formsets because I had two different relationships that I wanted to change from one form.

- one to many relationship
- many to many relationship

depending which side of the relationship and which relationship type one wants to edit from within a single form there are different approaches:

There is the inlineformset_factory:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets . This type of formset is used when one wants to edit the **many** side of a one to many relationship

If one wants to edit the one side of a one to many relationship the 
modelformset_factory gets used: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

one can create a model_formset, and then add this formset to the main formset of the main form.

when one wants to edit a many to many relationship within a single form, an inline_formset_factory can be created with the intermediary table of the many to many relationship.

this formset than can be added to main form.

For my use case that I described above I ended up using a model_formset_factory and added that to the main form.